# .NET Regex - "Not" Match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
12345678|[0]{8}|[1]{8}|[2]{8}|[3]{8}|[4]{8}|[5]{8}|[6]{8}|[7]{8}|[8]{8}|[9]{8}
```

which matches if the string contains 12345679 or 11111111 or 22222222 ... or ... 999999999.

How can I changed this to only match if NOT the above? (I am not able to just !IsMatch in the C# unfortunately)...EDIT because that is black box code to me and I am trying to set the regex in an existing config file

Comment: *"I am not able to just !IsMatch"* - Why not?

Comment: I guess the problem is to collect the "not match" in groups or similar or get it out of a string like 12345678important00000000

Comment: So is `112345678` something that you DO want to match? (Notice the extra `1` in front)

Comment: I can't just !IsMatch because that is black box code to me and I am trying to set the regex in an existing config file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will match everything...

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"^(?:(?!123456789|(\d)\1{7}).)*$");
```

**unless** one of the "*forbidden*" sequences is found in the string.

**Not** using `!isMatch` as you can see.

**Edit:**

Adding your second constraint can be done with a lookahead assertion:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"^(?=\d{9,12})(?:(?!123456789|(\d)\1{7}).)*$");
```

Comment: "^(?:(?!12345678|(\d)\1{7}).)*$" works perfectly, thanks very much

Comment: @DavidWard You're welcome. I thought that you made a typo with 12345678 :)

Comment: Could this easily be extended to also restrict length to between 9 and 12 chars? - happy to move to another question

Comment: @DavidWard Yes it could be, if you tell me what you mean by chars. Only digits? Or anything?

Comment: Good point, between 9 and 12 numeric characters (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9)

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly

```
string s = "55555555";

Regex regx = new Regex(@"^(?:12345678|(\d)\1{7})$");

if (!regx.IsMatch(s)) {
    Console.WriteLine("It does not match!!!");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("it matched");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Btw. I simplified your expression a bit and added anchors

```
^(?:12345678|(\d)\1{7})$
```

The `(\d)\1{7}` part takes a digit `\d` and the `\1` checks if this digit is repeated 7 more times.

**Update**

This regex is doing what you want

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"^(?!(?:12345678|(\d)\1{7})$).*$");
```

Comment: I think your regex still matches the code in your brackets. But it is shorter.

Comment: @David Ward I updated my answer with a solution that should match anything except what you not want.

Comment: This almost worked but matched 222222222 when it shouldn't...FailedDev answer below worked (when I changed the first rule to be only 12345678). Thanks for your help

Comment: @DavidWard OK, seems my solution is too strict here it will not match on exactly 8 times the same digit, but of course it will accept 9 repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need any of those `[]` brackets; you can just do `0{8}|1{8}|` etc.

Now for your problem. Try using a negative lookahead:

```
@"^(?:(?!123456789|(\d)\1{7}).)*$"
```

That should take care of your issue without using `!IsMatch`.

Comment: Note: I feel like atomic grouping would be better than the `(\d)\1{7}` construct, but I don't know atomic groups well enough to get it to work. Anyone who does would be welcome to comment.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware that you can quantify zero width assertions!

Comment: @FailedDev - My bad, I left out a pair of parentheses. Fixed.

Comment: That actually compiled in .net :S

Comment: @FailedDev - Good grief, you're right. The old version appears to match an empty string. I wonder what's going on internally, and how the lookahead is being applied. My guess is it has no effect, other than possibly slowing the engine down.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to just !IsMatch in the C# unfortunately.

Why not? What's wrong with the following solution?

```
bool notMatch = !Regex.Match(yourString, "^(12345678|[0]{8}|[1]{8}|[2]{8}|[3]{8}|[4]{8}|[5]{8}|[6]{8}|[7]{8}|[8]{8}|[9]{8})$");
```

That will match any string that contains more than just `12345678`, `11111111`, ..., `99999999`